# how to retrieve data from database in sqlite database ina android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have mainactivity in which i have  button of "insertrecipe". when user clicks button another activity will start using intent and will go from "mainactivity" to "insertrecipe" and user will be shown a text field in which he can type text and also a button of submit. when user done typing text and press "submit" button, this text should be entered into database and at the same time retrieve all the recipe from database which are currently present.

When user press the button "insertrecipe" following activity will be called:

```
import mad.project.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class InsertRecipeActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.insertrecipe);

    final EditText RecipeBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RecipeBox);
    Button submit_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitRecipe);

    final DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this); 


    submit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    String Recipe_Box = RecipeBox.getText().toString();
    db.Insert_Recipe_Into_DB(Recipe_Box);
    Intent mi = new Intent(InsertRecipeActivity.this, ShowRecipeActivity.class);
     startActivity(mi);
}
    });

}
```

}

In the above activity I am entering the recipe into databse using       db.Insert_Recipe_Into_DB(Recipe_Box); and then calling another activity "showrecipeactivity" whose code is as follows:

```
  public class ShowRecipeActivity extends ListActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     final DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
     String [] recipe ;
     String b="                     Recipe ";
     recipe= db.get_recipe();
     if((recipe==null) )
     {Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Menu didn't selected",               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
     }
     int b_len = recipe.length;
     int total=b_len+1;

     String [] todaymenu = new String[total];
     todaymenu[0]=b;
     for(int i = 1;i<=b_len;i++)
     {
         todaymenu[i]=recipe[i-1];
     }

     this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.show_recipe, R.id.Today ,todaymenu));

}
```

}

but this activity is not working I mean when I press "submit" button error shows "Forceclose". Can anyone help me in this please. my database table has onle one field of type text.

Comment: Can you add the contents from logcat?

Comment: what is logcat? can you please tell me where this file is located

Comment: logcat is the term used to define the logging output of Android and its applications. In your development environment, you can type from the commandline "adb logcat" to have the output go directly to your console, but you might be more comfortable with eclipse. You can enable the tab at the bottom by going Window->Show View->Other...->Android->logcat. Or, while you're running the app you can also open up the DDMS with more information (Window->Open Perspective->Other...->DDMS). It should show you why it's force closing. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html

Answer (score 0):

NewBoston Channel on youtube has tutorials on Android and in them, some of the tutorials cover using sqllite

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JyC_xv20yE

Tutorial 111 - 124 cover everything you need to about SQLlite. In his one, he has an application where you can enter data, retrieve, update, delete, so they should be very useful to you. The videos are not too long either and he explains them in detail.

I hope his videos help, they certainly helped me a lot.